# How to manage localhost with Instagram basic display API

Tags: facebook, oauth, instagram-api

I want to use Instagram basic display API but I have a problem with localhost Oauth callback URL.

In the developpment panel of Meta we are force to enter HTTPS callback URI. So how can i make it work in localhost ?

[images of meta developper panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GoO8.png)

[error code with http](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPmeb.png)

My code is working well if i use https://localhost:8000 but i'm not able retrieve data from here.

[instagram allow connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8uLl.png)

[sucess with https but no server handle it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulrze.png)

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: _"sucess with https but no server handle it"_ - you could just remove the `s` in your browser address bar, and call the HTTP version of that URL ... Or use a service like ngrok, that allows you to make your local machine available via a real HTTPS URL on the internet.

Comment: @CBroe i can't remove the "s" in the address bar because it's instagram who redirect the user to the "redirect URL" i gaved him. But i can't give him URL with http.

I'm going to look for ngrok.
Thank for your reply.

Comment: I meant that when you got redirected to the HTTPS version, which only makes your browser show an error because you do not have HTTPS on your server, you could remove the `s` from `https://` in the address bar, and press enter ... You're probably not going to need to test the login part constantly, so for just a quick test to get that step over and done with, that would be a quick workaround.

Comment: @CBroe Oh ok i'm stupid, I don't know why I think I'm losing data by forcing a refresh although it's a GET request...

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I know it is late but you can't use 'http://' as redirect URL in the meta app. They have updated the Meta app, which only allows https:// or SSL certified URLs.

and for the 2nd part,

if you want to retrieve the data then you need to create an API on the redirect URL which could handle the code coming from Instagram server.

and using code, get the access token, store it in the DB and use if for retrieving the media feeds.

Thanks